# Как закачать версию проекта определенного коммита в Source Tree?

Tags: git, source-tree

Как закачать версию проекта определенного коммита в Source Tree? Например он был два дня назад.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "версию проекта определенного коммита"? Может наоборот?

Comment: Да, у есть репозиторий, мне нужно скачать с одной ветки изменения которые были сделаны 2 дня назад.

Comment: В смысле скачать? Если вы используете программу для git репозитория, то данные у вас уже скачаны. Скорректируйте вопрос и напишите какой результат вам нужен и в чем проблема

Comment: Программа скаченная последний версии, а как вернуться ( скачать предыдущую) версию ?

Comment: А вы разбираетесь [в основах Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Введение-Основы-Git)? Дело в том, что вопрос очень странный. Вам нужен просто `checkout` на коммит и в вашей директории будут файлы нужной версии. В Source Tree достаточно два раза шелкнуть на коммит в истории

Comment: Отметил дубликатом к вопросу, где есть решения для разных ситуаций, в которых вы хотите получить версию проекта из определённого коммита. Если остаются вопросы, спрашивайте там в комментариях.